# Accessing an vector-Object from a different class

Tags: c++, class, object, vector

I created a vector with Pointers and I create new Objects from the class DigOut derived from Modul in one method called

```
BOOL Cbeckhoff_frontendDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
//...
std::vector<Modul*> arrDigOut;
arrDigOut.push_back(new DigOut(IDC_CHECK1, this,"GVL.DigOut1",pAddr));
//...
for(iNumDO = 0;iNumDO<1;iNumDO++) arrDigOut[iNumDO]->InitCheck(this);
//...
}
```

How can I access the vector from a different method like:

```
void Cbeckhoff_frontendDlg::OnBnClickedButton3()
{
for(iNumDO = 0;iNumDO<1;iNumDO++) arrDigOut[iNumDO]->SetID();
}
```

I thought about using public pointers or setters and getters,
 but I don't get to create membervariables like this:

```
std::vector<Modul*> *   parrDigOut;
```

where it's complaining, that Modul is not declared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example gives the impression you are declaring the `vector` at function scope. Its lifetime ends at the end of the function call (and all memory is leaked). Store it as a class member and a member functions `begin` and `end` that forward to the `begin` and `end` member functions of the `vector`. Possibly wrap them in a `dereference_iterator` to hide the fact that they are pointers.

```
class foo {
public:
  foo() { 
    // add things to s_
  }

  ~foo() { 
    // dont forget to delete everything in s_
  }
  typedef std::vector<my_stuff*>::iterator iterator;
  typedef std::vector<my_stuff*>::const_iterator const_iterator;
  iterator begin() { return s_.begin(); }
  iterator end() { return s_.end(); }
  const_iterator begin() const { return s_.begin(); }
  const_iterator end() const { return s_.end(); }

  // or to hide the pointers
  typedef boost::indirect_iterator< std::vector<my_stuff*>::iterator > iterator;
  iterator begin() { return boost::make_indirect_iterator(s_.begin()); }
  iterator end() { return boost::make_indirect_iterator(s_.end()); }
private:
  std::vector<my_stuff*> s_;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, just make it public and add this line before it:

```
class Modul;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a member variable as you described.
On top of the class declaration just provide a forward declaration,

```
class Modul;
```

This is to let the compiler know that such a class is going to get defined somewhere down the line.

The member variables need not be public as it is accessed from another function in the same class.

And just declare the member as:

```
std::vector<Modul*>   parrDigOut; //No need of pointers
```

However, you could think of using a smart pointer to make sure that it gets deleted when the parent class gets out of scope